# Watchkit to connect iphone device camera?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

Is it possible to connect WatchKit application to the iPhone device camera? I want the camera to appear in first screen of my application. So how to connect camera in WatchKit?

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty broad. Short answer? There's nothing built in to WatchKit for this kind of functionality. You'll have to open the camera from your iOS app and stream still images to the Watch.

Comment: How can I access images from my iPhone to watch app?

Comment: See this link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remotecam-live-preview-full-camera-photo-video-remote/id1046684036?mt=8

Comment: This app is doing the same. How can we do the same?